# If $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is unbounded, is it necessarily true that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |f(x)| = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

This question comes from the following problem:

> A real-valued function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ has the following property: For every positive $\epsilon$, there exists positive $\delta$ such that, $|f(x) - f(1)|\ge \epsilon$ whenever $|x-1|\ge\delta$.
>
> This property is **equivalent** to which of the following statements?
>
> (C). $f$ is unbounded
>
> (D). $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |f(x)|=\infty$

The answer is D and this is obvious if you write down the definition. However, I am trying to understand why C is not correct. Noticing that D implies C, yet C is not the correct answer, it has to be the case that C does not imply D. If my logic is right, does that mean we can find some $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that it is unbounded but $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |f(x)| \ne \infty$?

I cannot think of an example. I thought about $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ but it is not defined at $x=0$. Perhaps something is wrong with my logic here?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = e^{x}$.  $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}|f(x)|$ does not even exist (because it has different behavior for $\pm x \to \infty$).

Comment: It doesn't say $f$ has to be continuous; so we could let $f(x) = 1/x$ for $x\neq 0$, and $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @florence OHHHHH....... fair enough -_-

Comment: Another example, which might be more relevant, is $$f(x)=x\,\sin x.$$